# Unable to format HDD; Partitions & contents are retained after formatting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, debian

I have a Seagate Laptop HDD which I want to format.  Since I encountered problems formatting it while installing Windows 7, removed it and connected to PC using USB adapter.

Tried the following:

- Partition manager on Windows (All partitions are deleted; Formatting unallocated space fails after deleting all partitions)
- diskpart.exe on windows (clean)  (All partitions are deleted upon completion; But partitions reappear upon reconnecting the HDD with the original contents)
- kde partition manager on Debian/Linux (Shows as deleted; Old contents are retained)
- fdisk utility on Debian/Linux (No change in the partition table)
- dd utility on Debian/Linux (Failed with I/O error)

Please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

During windows installation :

Under the tab " Which type of installation do you want ?"

> Choose - Custom (advanced)

Then choose the required disk from the available list, and on the same screen there is a option called "Drive options(advanced)"

Choosing that will list few options - Delete, Format, Extent and New,

Now choose delete/format based on your requirement and reboot the system and proceed the installation from the live CD.

Comment: Already tried that approach. I could not complete the format step while reinstalling the OS. Getting an error 0x8xxxxx while formatting the partition.